# how to find difference between two lists

Tags: java, spring, collections

I have two lists. one is as follwos,

```
 public static final List<Integer> NATURAL_MANDATORY = 
                Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(1,2,4,5));
```

second list is as follows,

```
List<Integer> MandatoryList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

MandatoryList = [1,2];
```

I want to find what are the different between two list's, for that I have writern

```
Constants.NATURAL_MANDATORY.removeAll(MandatoryList);
```

I am getting

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

As it is unmodifiableList, Is there any way to find the difference between them

Comment: `NATURAL_MANDATORY` is unmodifiable and hence you cannot remove from it.

Comment: @user7 yes, you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot edit `unmodifiableList` as they are `read-only`. And in `removeAll` method, the elements of first lists which are in the second list are removed. So this operation can not be performed in `NATURAL_MANDATORY`. So if you must do it, then you can perhaps copy the elements to a new `List` and do this operation.

Answer (score 0):

You attempted to modify an `unmodifiableList`, that leads to `UnsupportedOperationException`.

You can use [`CollectionUtils.subtract()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#subtract(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable)) from Apache Commons Collections 4.0:

```
List<Integer> diffList = new ArrayList<>(CollectionUtils.subtract(NATURAL_MANDATORY, MandatoryList));
```